# ERROR; cannot use imageName (type ImageName) as type dao.ImageName in appendgo

Tags: go

I'm refactoring server side logic in Go, but there is error that I can't resolve.

```
・client: react/axios
・api: golang/gin
・web-server: nginx
・db: mysql
・container: docker
・ci-tool: travis
・deploy: aws elastic beanstalk
```

service.go

```golang
func GetSingleArticleService(c *gin.Context, db *sql.DB) Article {

    article, rows := dao.GetSingleArticleDao(c, db)
    for rows.Next() {
        imageName := ImageName{}
        err := rows.Scan(&imageName.NAME)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        // error occurs here
        article.IMAGENAMES = append(article.IMAGENAMES, imageName)
    }

    return article
}
```

dao.go

```golang
func GetSingleArticleDao(c *gin.Context, db *sql.DB) (Article, *sql.Rows) {
    id := c.Params.ByName("id")
    article := Article{}
    errArticle := db.QueryRow("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE id = ?", id).Scan(&article.ID, &article.UUID, &article.TITLE, &article.CONTENT)
    if errArticle != nil {
        panic(errArticle.Error())
    }
    rows, errImage := db.Query("SELECT image_name FROM images WHERE article_uuid  = ?", article.UUID)
    if errImage != nil {
        panic(errImage.Error())
    }

    return article, rows
}
```

I expect there is no compile error, but the actual is not. There is error at service.go.

```
cannot use imageName (type ImageName) as type dao.ImageName in append
```

Comment: Different packages --> different types. You may type convert if underlying type allows it. For fundamentals: Take the Tour of Go.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @ Volker, I make `util.go` file for common model and import it.

```
package util

type Article struct {
    ID         int         `json:"id"`
    UUID       string      `json:"uuid"`
    TITLE      string      `json:"title"`
    CONTENT    string      `json:"content"`
    IMAGENAMES []ImageName `json:"imageNames"`
}

type ImageName struct {
    NAME string `json:"name"`
}

type ImageData struct {
    ARTICLEUUID string      `json:"articleUUID"`
    IMAGENAMES  []ImageName `json:"imageNames"`
}
```